# What is an appropriate directory in which to install Android SDK?

Tags: android, linux

I don't use java much so what are the common (best practice) locations to install components like this.  I want to put them in a system directory so multiple users have access.

Comment: I'm not looking to do it half-assed.  Unix software has common places such as /opt.  I would like to know what is common for java/android packages and such.

Comment: i've said to you that it doesn't matter where , create a new directory and define the autorisation to all user to acces it , and then , pass the path on your Eclipse to refer the sdk ,

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Common locations are `/opt`, `/srv`, and `/usr/local`. I tend to lean toward `/usr/local`.

Note that the Android SDK doesn't really require you to install much, it's mostly self-contained. All you need to do is tell Eclipse where it is. You may also want to add the `tools` and/or `platform-tools` directories to the system-wide PATH so that your users can use adb and other tools.

See http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html.

Comment: Why do you tend to use `/usr/local`? Preference?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: Because it's the "correct" location for locally-installed software that isn't part of the standard distribution according to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). `/opt` is also perfectly valid, and some would argue that it's even more appropriate since the Android SDK is self-contained and doesn't itself follow the FHS. In fact, if I were to install the SDK today I might put it in `/opt` and then symlink to the binaries in `/usr/local` (since the latter location has the added benefit of being on the `PATH` by default).

Answer (score 16):

On Linux, I typically use `/usr/local/android-sdk`, but anywhere that makes sense and that won't get clobbered by your system works. Just be aware that it may actually make sense to put the SDK in a per-user location, since it requires write access to create a VM image and to download SDK updates.

Answer (score 0):

To be more concise and allow user writing for things like sdk installations and etc, you could put it somewhere inside the `~/.local` directory as per the [XDG file system hierarchy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) like `~/.local/lib/arch-id/android-sdk`
Also remember to set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` env variable to that directory as the `ANDROID_HOME` variable was deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

It doesnt matter where you put the sdk. Just put it in any folder where all user's can access it...