# Android ADB commands in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, ubuntu

can someone tell me how can i debug and use adb shell commands in Ubuntu 11.10 terminal? i just know how to use it in Windows.

Comment: Try what you know how to do in Windows and see if they work in Linux too? It'd be easier to give guidance if you are stuck on something specific...

Comment: i can't run adb in the terminal like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345157/running-adb-on-ubuntu-11-10-results-permission-denied.

Comment: can't install  ia32-libs, terminal says: Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: got the solution:
http://teambamf.net/showthread.php/2532-Easy-ADB-Eclipse-and-SDK-Setup-for-Ubuntu-11.04-and-Linux-Mint-11

Comment: Yikes, that install script sets mode `777` on content in `/usr/local/android-{sdk,npk}` and adds the `/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools/` directory to _everyone_'s path. **Never run that script on a multi-user system. It creates a serious security threat.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add platform-tools to environmental variable,for that

Append the following line to last of the /home/yourUserName/.bashrc file in your home folder..

> export PATH="your/path/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/:${PATH}"

Comment: where's the best directory to place Android SDK?

Comment: chk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535569/what-is-an-appropriate-directory-in-which-to-install-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the `ia32-libs` package is in multiverse:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ia32-libs

If you want to use the `ia32-libs` package, then you'll need to enable the `multiverse` portion of the repositories with some lines like this in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
```

(Replace **natty** with **oneiric** if you're on the newer distribution. Be sure you're consistent with the other entries in your config.)

Debian looks like it ought to be available easily enough:

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ia32-libs

Comment: is there another way rather than using ia32-libs? can't run sudo adb either

Comment: sudo has nothing to do here...

Comment: If you're on a 64 bit platform and trying to run 32 bit code, you'll need those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I post here my solution for ubuntu 11.10 64 bit!!

I was missing a java6 packet. I have install those: 
    sun-java6-bin, sun-java6-jre, sun-java6-jdk, sun-java6-plugin

and i was missing the plugin(last one)

My permissions were ok.

If problem with persmissions:

1. Connect your mobile with adb
2. type lsusb and copy the xxxx:xxxx vendor id
3. sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules
4. paste in here

   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="####:####", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"
   TEST=="/var/run/ConsoleKit/database", \
   RUN+="udev-acl --action=$env{action} –device=$env{DEVNAME}"

where ####:#### replace from what you copied in step 2.
Then save and close file.

1. sudo service udev restart
2. adb kill-server
3. adb start-server

**6,7 adb to work from any folder you must:

a. sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
b. Put lines at the bottom:

## Android SDK Tools

```
export PATH=${PATH}:your_path_to_androidsdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:your_path_to_androidsdk/platform-tools
```

To find your path to androidsdk,just navigate to it, and write pwd in terminal.
Paste the result of terminal as "your_path_to_androidsdk".

c. save and close! Make sure you dont put "your_path_to_androidsdk", but YOUR REAL PATH!

d. reboot(maybe logoff & login the trick, but didnt test.)